# How to get value from nested objects with array of keys in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I need to get value from nested objects with array of keys. I don't know in advance what the object will look like.And I can't describe keys type in the right way. Error occurs "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'".

```
const messages = { 
    "button": { 
        "alt": {
            "editButton": "editButton",
            "deleteButton": "deletebutton"
        }
}}

const getNested = (obj: object, keys: string[]) => keys.reduce((p, c) => p?.hasOwnProperty(c) ? p[c] : null, obj);
```

Comment: This code is quite confusing. Could you give an example usage of `getNested` and what you'd expect the corresponding output to be?

Comment: Here's my type-safe solution: https://tsplay.dev/m3BXAN Still working on getting the intellisense suggestions right...

Comment: So, I ended up fixing it with currying: https://tsplay.dev/mMz1bW If it fits your needs, let me know and I may write up an answer explaining it (please use @pink in replies).

Answer (score 0):

You can convince the compiler that the accesses are safe by adding the requisite checks like below. Since your example only has string values I've created it for strings below:

```
type StringRecord = Record<string, string>
type RecNested = StringRecord | {
  [key: string]: string | StringRecord | {
    [k: string]: RecNested
  }
} | {
  [key: string]: RecNested
}
function getNestedProp(o:RecNested, path: string[]): string | undefined {
  const [key, ...rest] = path;
  if (key in o) {
    const val = o[key];
    if (typeof val === 'string') {
      return val;
    }
    
    const foo = val;
    return getNestedProp(val, rest)
  }

  return;
}

const messages = { 
    "button": { 
        "alt": {
            "editButton": "editButton",
            "deleteButton": "deletebutton"
        }
}}

const foo = getNestedProp(messages, ["button", "alt", "deleteButton"])
```

Note that if you can tolerate a little more complexity you can make the return value generic instead of a known concrete type:

```
type SomeRecord<T> = Record<string, T>
type RecNested2<T> = SomeRecord<T> | {
  [key: string]: T | SomeRecord<T> | {
    [k: string]: RecNested2<T>
  }
} | {
  [key: string]: RecNested2<T>
}

function isString(x: unknown): x is string {
  return typeof x === 'string'
}

function getNestedProp2<T>(o: RecNested2<T>, path: string[], validator: (x: unknown) => x is T): T | undefined {
  const [key, ...rest] = path;
  if (key in o) {
    const val = o[key];
    if (validator(val)) {
      return val
    }

    return getNestedProp2(val, rest, validator);
  }

  return;
}

const bar = getNestedProp2<string>(messages, ["button", "alt", "deleteButton"], isString)
```

NOTE: this only really works if your nested object's leaf values are all of the same type. It looks like user Pink's suggestion in the comments can give you arbitrary leaf types, although it seems to be a possibly a little hard for the compiler with intellisense. Hopefully they write an even better answer.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=34&ssc=1&pln=61&pc=90#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwEoQMYHt4BMoBeKTXAgHgGcEVUAaKGpNAPgChRJTsA5CGhEIk4LDNjyEAPlADe7KFADaAawggAXE1poAuluZ0oM0XTKTjchYuUqDO1Pp5Z+g-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-Iaz7gqcaI0rcCmpCBE5gVW0knESpQoacaEYfATSQip6IgmC1Lkm6vKVPAMzepp+I1j8qCsAGzKsgIobhvaMZRic0qxjaiYRhquiMCR+6oKSQA)